# Вообще не работает Design Editor

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design

Вся суть проблемы на картинке: Окно предпросмотра дизайна просто отсутсвует
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: refresh пробовали сделать?

Comment: В правом верхнем углу красный значок  с восклицательным знаком - нажмите, он расскажет, что мешает превью работать

Comment: build -> rebuild project, если не помогло - sync project with gradle files, если не помогло - File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart

Comment: ошибки исправил - дизайн стал отобрадаться - но после любого измеения уезажет в левый верхний угол и больше не активен.